# Subtract constant from Excel PivotTable values

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel Pivot Table that aggregates `Values` via the `Product` summary function.  I want to subtract 1 from all of the displayed values.

For example, if this is the pivot table containing `Values` = `Product` of source column "Return":

[image: Current pivot table]

What I actually want is a pivot table that displays `Values = Values - 1`:

[image: Desired pivot table]

What methods can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add calculated field to Pivot:

1. Click anywhere into pivottable
2. Go to ribbon `Pivottable tools`->`Analyze`
3. Open menu `Fields,Items&Sets`, choose `Calculated field`

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem: Product[x[i]-1] does not equal Product[x[i]]-1.